# On iOS, if we use Interface Builder for the UIViewController's view, how do we implement a drawRect for it?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

If we use Interface Builder to edit the content in the view, then how do we add a `drawRect` to that `UIView` object?  (Probably we want a new class `FooView` that subclasses `UIView` -- but how will the `.xib` content be placed on this view?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "content" to the view controller's view in the xib just involves adding subviews - these are not affected by `drawRect:`.

That said, to set a custom class as the main `view` property of a view controller, just select the view in the xib, go to the identity inspector, and change the class from UIView to your custom class.

Comment: I see... now I understand what that "Custom Class" is for -- it means I don't want `UIView` to be the class of this object, I want some other class, such as `FooView`... or even `UIImageView`, although probably you want your own subclass of `UIView`... so similarly, you can say, I don't want this button to be the class of `UIButton` -- I want it to be `MySuperButton`

Answer (score 1):

At beginning i want to point that i have done something like this(subclassing) with [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)
and since UIButton is inherited from UIView this must be possible with UIView too.

(after subclassing UIView) create an instance of your subclass on your view controller and add this instance to ViewController as subview. At this point you can call your specific drawRect: method, which you have declared on your subclass